# How to extract numbers from a scanner

Tags: java

I need help with a little code. 
I need to use `Scanner in = new Scanner("123 232 2323");`

and get this result in the terminal inside Intellij:

```
123 
232 
2323
```

Thanks!

Comment: so you want/ have to print the numbers with a scanner? or do you want to read?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `nextInt` while there is one and print integers to the console.

```
while (in.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println(in.nextInt());
}
```

Comment: Thank u Manos, it helped alot!

Answer (score 0):

try to use hasNext() and nextLine()  methods of scanner class, like:

```html
String res;
while(in.hasNext()){
  res += in.nextLine();
}

System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: 1. Code snippets are for JavaScript, not Java. 2. If you are calling `nextLine()`, you should be checking `hasNextLine()`, not `hasNext()`.